# Why is $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{(\sqrt{x})!}{(\sqrt{x+1})!}$ = 1 and not 0?

Tags: limits, radicals, factorial

Wouldn't we expect it to be equal to 0? I suspect that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}}$ should be equal to $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{(\sqrt{x})!}{(\sqrt{x+1})!}$. And the limit of the former is 0. Why is this not the case for the latter?

Comment: $0$ is  the correct answer.

Comment: Is the factorial done *after* the square root on top and bottom?

Comment: What you have written is not clear.  $(\sqrt x)!$ is very different from $\sqrt {x!\,}$  Please edit for clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $(\sqrt{x+1})!\neq \sqrt{(x+1)!}$. In the former case note that
$$
\sqrt {x + 1}  = \sqrt x \sqrt {1 + \frac{1}{x}}  = \sqrt x  + \frac{1}{{2\sqrt x }} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{x}} \right).
$$
Now for fixed $a$ and $b$,
$$
\frac{{(z + a)!}}{{(z + b)!}} = \frac{{\Gamma (z + 1 + a)}}{{\Gamma (z + 1 + b)}} \sim z^{a - b} 
$$
as $z\to +\infty$ (see [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11.E12)). Thus,
$$
\frac{{(\sqrt x )!}}{{(\sqrt {x + 1} )!}} \!=\! \frac{{\Gamma (\sqrt x  + 1)}}{{\Gamma (\sqrt {x + 1}  + 1)}} \!=\! \frac{{\Gamma (\sqrt x  + 1)}}{{\Gamma \left( {\sqrt x  + 1 + \frac{1}{{2\sqrt x }} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{x}} \right)} \right)}} \sim (\sqrt x )^{ - \frac{1}{{2\sqrt x }}}  \!=\! \mathrm{e}^{ - \frac{1}{4}\frac{{\log x}}{{\sqrt x }}}  \to 1
$$ as $x\to +\infty$.